# Can I Install Ghost BSD on an NTFS partition?

Tags: ubuntu, ntfs, bsd

I have installed ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop. And decided to check out Ghost BSD. Two of my drives are formatted using NTFS so that Windows installation can access.

So i have prepared one of drives and started Ghost BSD and started installing selected the partition (in which GBSD has to be installed) where Linux Mint was installed and was formatted using ext4. It showed some messages like preparing partition (Not the exact message) then showed an Error Message "Cannot Mount 260 GB partition" which is NTFS and exited installation.

When i restarted laptop GRUB was gone and i was not able to boot. So my question is Whether its not possible to install Ghost BSD in a hard drive which has NTFS partition ?

I have managed to reinstall GRUB using ubuntu live CD. But i would like to install both OS.

EDIT : I have selected the option 'Install BSD Boot loader' while installing

Sorry for the poor English. I',m from non English speaking country.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install GhostBSD on hard drive with NTFS.But not in a NTFS partition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have divided my hard drive into 4 partitions. 2 NTFS partitions and 2 ext4 partitions. I have used one of ext4 partition and selected to format the drive using UFS. And selected the option 'Install BSD Boot loader'. but while installing two Message boxes popped up showing 'Unable to Mount 260 GB partition' and another Message box showing unable to mount 'Windows XP partition'. '260 GB' and 'Windows XP' are label given to the drive using Gparted